# nginx proxy request buffering is not working as expected

Tags: http, nginx, file-upload, upload, tornado

This is my nginx config :

```
worker_processes auto;
user nginx;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {

    tcp_nodelay               on;
    add_header Cache-Control  no-cache;

    upstream servers {
        server                127.0.0.1:9999;
        server                127.0.0.1:9998;
    }

    proxy_request_buffering   on;

 server {
   listen 80;
   client_max_body_size 200M;
   client_body_buffer_size 200M;

   server_name           localhost;

        location / {
            try_files    $uri @proxy_upload;
        }

        location @proxy_upload {
            proxy_pass_request_body on;
            proxy_pass              http://servers;
        }

 }
}
```

I try to upload files, I am doing something like a chunked upload, files are more than 2G, client send files in chunks, the nginx and the script are working, but nginx is not working as expected

you see, I turned proxy_request_buffering on, so I expect nginx buffer all 200M of file and then pass it to back-end(which is tornado-python) at once, but nginx pass it to back-end in 1M or 2M chunks, this behavior lead to very higher cpu usage, higher system load and lower upload speed, this behavior is not much different than setting proxy_request_buffering to off, so I think I am doing somehthing wrong here

why is nginx not buffering correctly and how am I suppose to make nginx buffer the whole request and then pass it at once ?

I tried to use post_action, but I couldn't pass request body to back-end

UPDATE: Nginx is buffering correctly, I mean it pass request body to back-end as soon as whole file uploaded by client, but Nginx pass request body to back-end in smaller chunk and it won't pass it at once, It has whole body but it won't pass the whole body at once, How can I tell to nginx to pass request body to back-end at once ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to turn on `proxy_buffering`, set `proxy_buffers` to set the number and size of the buffers, and probably `proxy_buffers_size`  to ensure it doesn't overuse memory:

```
location @proxy_upload {
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffers 10 200m;
    proxy_buffer_size 1000m;
    proxy_pass_request_body on;
    proxy_pass              http://servers;
}
```

Not sure how much traffic your upstream server gets, but I could imagine buffers this large isn't that efficient ... What webserver are you using upstream that requires such a large buffer? Perhaps try incrementing the buffer 1m at a time until it's at a decent sweet spot.

From: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffers

And: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffer_size

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think proxy_buffers is the answer here, I tested a lot with the configuration you provided, but I think it's more related to back-end response to client, either way, there was no changes in result, as I said, I think proxy_buffers is about responses and I need to change behavior about requests